# Xcode Debug Memory Graph memory detects block leaked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use Xcode **Debug Memory Graph** tool to detect the memory leak. I got the following issues:

[image]

The AddPhotoCC is a UICollectionViewCell. The code is:

```
protocol AddPhotoCCDelegate : class {        
    func deleteImageView(index:Int)
}

class AddPhotoCC: UICollectionViewCell {        
    @IBOutlet weak var offenceImageView: UIImageView!
    weak var delegate: AddPhotoCCDelegate?
    var cellIndex:Int?

    @IBAction func deleteImageButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {            
        delegate?.deleteImageView(index:cellIndex!)            
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain what does this mean? What is **malloc<64>**? How can I solve the memory leak in this case? Thanks.